# Keep focus on element behind other (z-order) when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got an image, and using JQuery  I've got it so that the image will increase in size when you hover over it and a DIV that sits under the image will slide up and provide an overlay on the image that is half opacity and occupy the bottom half of the image area.

This works fine, however when you then hover over the overlay (but still on the same area as the image), the image scales down again because you're no longer focused on the image, so the hover out event gets fired.

How do you ignore the overlay when hovering as if to say "I don't care when you hover over the overlay, so long as you're still in the area of the image"?

Comment: It is much easier to help you if you provide a live example. http://jsfiddle.net/ is perfect for that

Answer (score 0):

You could use mousemove event instead of mouseenter and mouseleave and use image dimensions to determine if mouse is over the image.

Example:

```
        $(window).mousemove(function(evt) {
            var image = $("#image");
            var imageX0 = image.offset().left 
            var imageY0 = image.offset().top
            var imageX1 = imageX0 + image.width()
            var imageY1 = imageY0 + image.height()
            if( evt.pageX >= imageX0 && evt.pageX <= imageX1 && evt.pageY >= imageY0 && evt.pageY <= imageY1) {
                $("#status").text('Hovered!')
            } else {
                $("#status").text('Not hovered')
            }

        })
```

Check out live here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/486054/stackoverflow/hover-overlay.html

Comment: Hmmm the problem is that the image will increase in size when you hover over it, using the HoverPulse script at [link]http://jquery.malsup.com/hoverpulse/. and there are multiple images on the screen such as that example, so I'm not sure if a window event is the best solution here. I'll try when I can get my hands on the code tomorrow at my other computer and see.

Comment: You can add mousemove handler for every image (change $("#image") to actual image object), and, as you can see, handler calculates current dimensions each time (not quite optimal for performance). So basically it should work with multiple images and properly handle image resize.